# GoLang gRPC client on raspberryPI (armv7l) fails to handshake TLS 1.3

Tags: go, grpc, tls1.3

I have a gRPC client written in GoLang that I'm running on raspberryPI 4 (armv7l).
When I run the client on my MacBook it connects to the server and everything is fine.
When I run the same client on RaspberryPI 4, I get an error:

> transport: authentication handshake failed: tls: server selected unadvertised ALPN protocol

Looking at the standard library, I checked that this check fails:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/346b18ee9d15410ab08dd583787c64dbed0666d2/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client_tls13.go#L399

Function `checkALPN` is defined here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/346b18ee9d15410ab08dd583787c64dbed0666d2/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client.go#L752

I printed `clientProtos []string`, `serverProto string` and it turns out that when code is run on MacBook, clientProtos contains `h2` (which stands for HTTP2) and serverProto is `h2` which is fine, they match and the connection gets established according to protocol.

When the same code is run on RaspberryPI, clientProtos is `http/1.1` and server proto is `h2` (gRPC connection can be established only over HTTP2) so there's a mismatch so the client fails to connect and says "server selected unadvertised ALPN protocol" which makes total sense. Any hints on how to proceed? Is there a reason why the client on RaspberryPI doesn't want to use `HTTP2`? Or maybe I have to set it somewhere? Or install something? Not sure how to proceed here and Google doesn't help. I also tried compiling client code with GoLang 1.16 but got the same error